# What does "one" mean or stand for in "Hey, I'm on my way, all right? One."?

Tags: phrase-meaning, expressions, spoken-english, colloquial-language, numerals

In this movie two brothers are talking on the phone:

> — Yo
>  — Hey, Isaiah. Hey, are you going to pick me up, man?
>  —
>   You all right? What happened?
>  — Man, just some skinheads
>   tripping, man.
>  — All right, I'll be there as soon as I can, all
>   right? Taking care of some business for Armand.
>  [...]
>   — Look man, I really need to speak to you, man, for real. I got some
>   sh** to run by you.
>  — Hey, I'm on my way, all right? **One**.
>
> [ Urban Justice (2007, Don E. FauntLeRoy) ]

Does that *one* mean anything outside of this context, is it based on the idiom [*at one*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/one?s=t) as in *in a state of agreement/united in thought or feeling*? Or is that more along the lines of *see you in a minute* but literally *one* minute? Is it like "copy" or "over" on "military radio", or a binary exit status of some kind inspired by an IT metaphor, is it the equivalent of *ok*, is it a figure of speech, making the issue be the only one thing on his mind (an exaggeration), just pure styling, or something else?

---

In so many words is it a phrase, what is it related to and what does it mean?

Comment: What are the missing "[...]" lines? What was the sentence after the last sentence quoted? According to Urban Dictionary, [one](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=One) can mean "goodbye". I believe it, but I don't think I've ever heard that before.

Comment: "One" in this context means _goodbye._ It was a kind a hopeful parting originally, comin from a Rastafarian meanin of _[One Love.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdB-8eLEW8g)_ The peaceful drained away somewhat, and it just means _Later_ now, I think. I still hear it from elder musicians from time to time. I can't imagine it being used appropriately in a Steven Seagal film, though.

Comment: It's difficult for me to hear what exactly the character says at the end of that line, and it's not important to the story, so I would have mostly ignored it.  The rest of the dialogue seems reasonably accurate, at least by Hollywood standards, so I assume it was written by someone familiar with the dialect, and who had heard "one" used as slang for "goodbye".  As with all slang the use is probably limited to a particular group at a particular time -- it wasn't so long ago this same character would have ended with "Peace out!" or just "Peace!"  So I wouldn't attach too much significance to it.

Comment: Can I use it in an email?

Comment: @Max The missing lines are Isaiah talking to his friend who's in the car with him and who's abusing the substance so there's cursing and for a moment Gary (the younger brother) is confused by what he hears and Isaiah shortly explains the situation.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Can one equate the Rastafarian meaning of _One Love_ to the meaning of the _at one_ idiom generally?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Originally, the parting wish _One_ which partook of the sentiment of Marley's song, conveyed to the listener the hope that she, and everyone, would eventually be "at one" with each other in the uniting spirit of Ras Tafari or "Jah". This is not an uncommon parting wish; cf. _Vaya Con Dios,_ and _Allah Ma'ak_ (usually spoken only to other Muslims, but in the same vein at least.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Urban Dictionary, *one* means *goodbye*:

> [one](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=One)
>
> - "Goodbye"
>     Shortened form of "One Love"
>     "I'm out, 1"
> - Can be used as 'goodbye' or 'later'.
>     Short for "One Love"
>     Joe: "see ya tomorrow"
>     Nikki: "one."

It makes sense, especially if the speaker hangs up right after.

Comment: Thank you! I should have checked Urban D. but I'm not always in the mood for the sexist and/or prejudiced material I end up finding there. But the answer was there indeed.